# Have anyone the same problem? Colorpicker in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I made a colorpicker in MVC it works but know it doesn't work anymore.
I have this error "InvalidOperationException: Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions."

I tried everything. tried some old code that was a test version. and it doesn't work.

I am new to MVC. I make a webinterface to control ledstrips.

Html code:

```
<div class="Index-Wrapper">
<form action="/Lichten/LedStripOn" method="post">
    @Html.EditorFor(T => T.Color, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">ON</button>
</form>

<button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Html.Action("LedStripOff","Lichten")'">OFF</button>
```

ControllerCode :

```
// GET: Lichten
    public ActionResult LedStrip()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: Lichten/LedStripOn
    public ActionResult LedStripOn(Models.LedStrip form)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.Kleur = form.Color;
            int R = Convert.ToInt32(form.Color.Substring(1, 2), 16);
            int G = Convert.ToInt32(form.Color.Substring(3, 2), 16);
            int B = Convert.ToInt32(form.Color.Substring(5, 2), 16);

            ViewBag.R = R;
            ViewBag.G = G;
            ViewBag.B = B;

            /*SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM5", 9600);
            mySerialPort.Open();
            mySerialPort.Write(1 + ";" + R + ";" + G + ";" + B);
            mySerialPort.Close();
            */

            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return View("LedStrip", form);
        }


    }

    // GET: Lichten
    public ActionResult LedStripOff()
    {
        /*SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM5", 9600);
        mySerialPort.Open();
        mySerialPort.Write(0);
        mySerialPort.Close();
        */
        return RedirectToAction("LedStrip");
    }
```

Errormessage:

```
InvalidOperationException: Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.
```

Comment: It probably doesn't like the fact that LedStripOff is redirecting from a client request through location.href.  Can you invoke an ajax request to the off method, and then if successful, return Json indicating so and redirect to LedStrip from javascript instead?

Comment: I think the problem lies in this line: onclick="location.href='@Html.Action("LedStripOff","Lichten")'"  Change Html.Action to Url.Action.